# Issue with photo echo in php, simple task

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code in php and it's supposed to print me the image but it isn't.

Is there any problem with this code?
Thanks!

```
 echo "<td> <img src=foto/photo1/".$row['photo'] . "
  ></td>";
echo "<td> <img src=foto/photo2/".$row['photo2'] . "></td>";
```

Comment: Why are you showing PHP without any HTML? Either the problem is that the HTML you are generating isn't what you expect (so you should show both and ask how to change the PHP so it generates the HTML you want) or the HTML you get doesn't give the result you expect (so forget about the PHP and ask about the HTML).

Comment: Hello Quentin, thanks, the problem is that it isn't showing the image, so it might be a problem with generating the html i want. I just need to generate the img src code using php

Comment: You haven't said what the HTML you want is.

Comment: That sounds like a description of what you want the browser to render when it is given the HTML, not the HTML itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed the ' marks in the echo. Try this:

```
echo '<td> <img src="foto/photo1/'.$row['photo'].'"></td>';
echo '<td> <img src="foto/photo2/'.$row['photo2'].'"></td>';
```

Comment: Try to dump the $row variable to see its content.

Comment: What's the output of $row['photo'] ?

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes `'` for image src attribute.

Change your code like this

```
<img src='foto/photo1/".$row['photo'] ."'></td>
```